# Replace gsd-screensaver-proxy with light-locker

Tags: gnome, 20.04, lightdm, gnome-screensaver, light-locker

I'm currently using a fork of Antergos web-greeter because I don't like the default. However I can't use the default screensaver because if I lock through that I can simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to circumvent the login and be back in my session (the web-greeter runs on tty8). This is a big problem which I was able to solve by using light-locker. This worked fine until I upgraded to 20.04. Now `light-locker` won't start because `gsd-screensaver-proxy` is already running. I tried to solve that by setting the value in `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.screensaver-proxy` to false. That didn't work. Does anyone know how I can either stop `gsd-screensaver-proxy` from starting automatically and how to use `light-locker` instead? I would also be happy if there is a way to ditch `light-locker` completely and use the default instead.